# how remove Colored box (frame) from android studio Tabs

Tags: android-studio, tabs, ide, colorbox

It was a mistake to make this blue sticker appear around the Android Studio tabs. How to fix it ?!

**NOTE** : I am talking about IDE not Tabs in Android programming !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can solved this problem by using File Colors.

[image]

Comment: tnx , but your solution  
 didn't solve my problem solve my problem